# KeyLookup in massive columns in sql server

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I have one simple query which has multiple columns (more than 1000).
When i run with single column it gives me result in 2 seconds with proper index seek, logical read, cpu and every thing is under thresholds.

But when i select more than 1000 columns it takes 11 mins for the result and gives me key lookup.

You folks have you faced this type of issue?
Any suggestion on that issue?

Comment: My suggestion is to include those columns in a covering index. But still, please test.

Comment: Hi Felix,Thanks for reply. but i have more than 1000 column to add. is it good idea to add this? this query will run one in year

Comment: You should compare the actual execution plans of both cases to see where the time spent...

Comment: Peter, its key lookup which taking too much time

Comment: @NiravGajjar If it's only executed once a year, then the `LOOKUP` is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would suggest to add those columns in the `INCLUDE` fields of your non-clustered index. Adding them in the `INCLUDE` removes the `LOOKUP` in the execution plan. But as everything with SQL Server, it depends. Depending on how the table is used i.e, if you're updating the table more than just plain `SELECT`ing on it, then the `LOOKUP` might be ok.

Answer (score 0):

If this query is run once per year, the overhead of additional index is probably not worth it. If you need quick response time, that single time of the year when it needs to be run, look into 'pre executing' it and just present the result to the user.

The difference in your query plan might be because of join elimination (if your query contains JOINs with multiple tables) or just that the additional columns you are requesting do not exist in your currently existing indexes...